# SQL "FOR XML PATH" returns DISTINCT error

Tags: sql, xml

I am a SQL newbie. But I have succeeded getting something out in XML as I need.

This works:

```
SELECT
    'update' AS                 "@mode"
    ,'DN_Dimension' AS          CS_FT_ID
    ,'DN Dimension' AS          "CS_FT_NAMES/CS_FT_NAME"
    ,'string' AS                "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_DATATYPE"
    ,'multivalent' AS           "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_VALENCY"
    ,(SELECT
          DNDim.Code AS             "CS_FT_VALUE_ID"
          ,CASE WHEN DNDim.Description='' THEN DNDim.Code ELSE DNDim.Description END "CS_FT_DATA"
      FROM 
          [Master Data Repository$DN Dimension] DNDim
      FOR XML PATH ('CS_FT_VALUE'), ROOT ('CS_FT_VALUES'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('CS_FEATURE_TEMPLATE'), ROOT ('CS_FEATURE_TEMPLATES');
```

But I would like to UNION data from more tables. So I tried with this:

```
SELECT
'update' AS                 "@mode"
,'DN_Dimension' AS          CS_FT_ID
,'DN Dimension' AS          "CS_FT_NAMES/CS_FT_NAME"
,'string' AS                "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_DATATYPE"
,'multivalent' AS           "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_VALENCY"
,(SELECT
DNDim.Code AS               "CS_FT_VALUE_ID"
,CASE WHEN DNDim.Description='' THEN DNDim.Code ELSE DNDim.Description END "CS_FT_DATA"
FROM [Master Data Repository$DN Dimension] DNDim
FOR XML PATH ('CS_FT_VALUE'), ROOT ('CS_FT_VALUES'),TYPE
)
UNION
SELECT
    'update' AS                 "@mode"
    ,'Max_Pressure' AS          CS_FT_ID
    ,'Max. Operating Pressure' AS "CS_FT_NAMES/CS_FT_NAME"
    ,'string' AS                "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_DATATYPE"
    ,'multivalent' AS           "CS_FT_CONTENT/CS_FT_VALENCY"
    ,(SELECT
    MaxOP.Code AS               "CS_FT_VALUE_ID"
    ,CASE WHEN MaxOP.Description='' THEN MaxOP.Code ELSE MaxOP.Description END "CS_FT_DATA"
    FROM [Master Data Repository$Max_ Operating Pressure] MaxOP
    FOR XML PATH ('CS_FT_VALUE'), ROOT ('CS_FT_VALUES'),TYPE
    )
FOR XML PATH ('CS_FEATURE_TEMPLATE'), ROOT ('CS_FEATURE_TEMPLATES');
```

Now I get error

> The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

even though I don't use DISTINCT in queries.

I can get rid of them by removing TYPE in the sub-queries FOR XML PATH's - but then the elements of the sub-queries are not returned correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between single quotes and double quotes.  I can't make sense of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Regarding the error: You are using `union`, this applies `distinct` to your result set. Use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: `UNION` invokes a `DISTINCT`.  Use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Halleluja :-)
It's the little things. UNION ALL solved it. Thanks to HoneyBadger and Siyal